# Documents that appear in more than one category are pasted multiple times when using Copy Selected As Table

Tags: lotus-notes, notesview

I have to fix the problem in the title and after one day of research I realy don't know what else to try, what else to google ;)

The topic is discussed in an IBM [TechNote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21173520).

But this answer isn't enough for me. I really need a workaround!

My question: Can I 'get between' the User clicking the 'Copy as table' and the actual copying of the table?

I see two ways of solving my problem (I don't know how to implement them):

1. If I just could show the user a Messagebox 'Use our own export agent' that would be great.
2. If I could convince Notes to just copy each document only once that would be even greater.

If I should make my question more precise, just ask. I will gladly edit it!

Every answer would be highly appreciated. Out of the box thinking, other approaches, I like to hear your opinion!

Friendly Greetings

Josi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to hook in and alter the results of the Copy Selected as Table method.  If it is possible to show an "Export Friendly" view that is not categorized, that is one way to solve the problem.

I'm not sure how useful it will be to you, but many years ago I wrote a sample project for [exporting views to Excel](http://partialclass.blogspot.com/2009/02/export-to-excel-20-for-lotus-notes.html), and that should handle categorized views properly.  There are surely other options available by now too (though I'm not familiar with them).

Comment: Typically, my users didn't know how to Copy Selected as Table, so if you can provide them ways to do it directly, as Ken suggests, rather than via 3-5 steps that copying requires, they're more likely to use that (especially if you can do some of the formatting for them).

Comment: My Users know the 'Copy as Table' feature and use it. Aaaand they are not happy if it doesn't respond as they expect it to.

Imho the exportfriendly view isn't an option because the categorisation is quite need. ;)

Thanks for the Exportagent. We already have an Excel export and this one works fine. Thats why it would be great if I could show the 'copy as table'-clicking user a Messagebox 'Use our export agent'.

But well. If I don't get an Geistesblitz I will just put the exportagent in an more prominent place.

Thanks for your answers and your time!